# How to use Python `secret` module to generate random integer?

Tags: python, security, random, python-3.6

In Python 3.6, [new module, `secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/secrets.html), was added.

What is the most efficient way to generate random integer in range `[n, m)` using this module?

I tried `choice(range(n, m))`, but I doubt it is the best way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`secrets.choice(range(n, m))` should be fine, since `range` is lazy on Python 3.

`n + secrets.randbelow(m-n)` is another option. I wouldn't use it, since it's less obviously correct.

Since `secrets` provides access to the `SystemRandom` class, with the same interface as `random.Random`, you can also keep your own `SystemRandom` instance:

```
my_secure_rng = secrets.SystemRandom()
```

and do

```
my_secure_rng.randrange(n, m)
```

Comment: ```my_secure_rng.randrange(1000, 9999)```

How to generate 4 digit number without all same digits? I need a number except any of it 1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999.

Answer (score 7):

The `secret` module provides the same interface as `random`; the underlying random generator has just been changed to `SystemRandom` which is cryptographically strong.

In short, use it as you would `random` in circumstances that require a bit more security; I doubt `choice` suffers from performance so much to warrant your concern.

Answer (score 5):

```
import secrets
num = secrets.randbelow(50)
print(num)
```

Comment: Please give more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Not enough rep to comment but to add on to user2357112's answer if you run a quick execution time test they actually report basically identical.

```
Best of 3 trials with 1,000,000 loops per trial:
        randrange() 1.39906 seconds total time.
        choice() 1.39431 seconds total time.
```